# how does Buildroot support dependencies on headers & libs without source

Tags: cmake, embedded-linux, buildroot, build-system

- I am considering to add multiple packages/modules based on Buildroot. Normally, when compiling is executed, the script will clone the source code of the package from the repository and build and install according to the dependencies.
- Suppose there is A B C D in the Buildroot packages. And A depends on B. B is developed and maintained by other colleagues. I am only responsible for the development of A and do not have the code permissions of B. So can I not complete the compilation according to the normal execution of `make`?
- My expectation is to be able to successfully complete the development and packaging of A when B’s code permissions do not exist, but B’s object files, development header files and library files exist. Are there any methods or suggestions?

Comment: Now it's more or less clear, thanks for your effort. To the topic: you need to provide a *binary* package to the Buildroot (I believe you may produce one, although I never heard about this to be advirtised). So, basically what you need is to **install** the headers and libraries to the $(TARGET_DIR) folder. Since Buildroot caches target folder (if you don't run `make clean` in between) you may install them even manually, but I highly recommend to do it in a form of package with a commit in the Git of Buildroot (local) repository.

Comment: Thanks for your continued attention, I will boldly try to use the header files and libraries of B to complete the compilation of A, and I will update later, it will be later, I hope there is a cool result